# Как получить значения из массива?

Tags: vue.js

С сервера я получаю записи, например, `{ "when": "1999-01-08" }`, но мне нужно только значение `1999-01-08`. У меня получилось достать нужные данные, но запись получилась слишком громоздкой. Как мне укоротить код?

```
<div v-for="(value, name) in days"> 
    <div v-for="(value, name) in value">
        {{ value }}
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

если у вас данные:

```
data: {
    days: [
      { when: '1999-01-08' },
      { when: '1999-01-10' }
    ]
  }
```

то так:

```
<div v-for="item in days" :key="item.when">
    {{ item.when }}
</div>
```

документация тут: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html